# Why would Android stop receiving GCM messages on particular IP address?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have a large scale project with hundreds of devices out in the field that I communicate with using GCM. Recently I've been experiencing a strange issue where many of these devices have stopped responding to my GCM messages. A couple things to note:

1. Sending my payload to Google's GCM servers still returns a proper 200 response.
2. The GCM keys for these devices have been verified to be correct/active.
3. The device will start receiving GCM messages if I move the device to a different network/subnet.
4. The device will start receiving GCM messages if I change its IP address on the same network.
5. The device will start receiving GCM messages with its initial IP address if I clear data of the Google Playservices package and restart my application.

It seems as if the socket for GCM has gotten stuck in a disconnected state and does not reconnect. These devices are typically connected via wifi which does sometimes drop, however... This past weekend, over 100 of these devices stopped responded so that leads me to believe some sort of TTL has expired and a refresh never happened.

Has anyone experienced anything like this before, or have any thoughts or suggestions about this?

Comment: Just to be clear you are using the older GCM and not the Firebase implementation? If so are you able to upgrade to Firebase?

Comment: @Barns yes that is correct. Migrating to Firebase and/or MQTT has been discussed but as of now there aren't any plans put in place.

Comment: I wish I could help more, but I have no experience with GCM. I do use FCM and have not experienced the issue you have described. I have had some delay in receiving messages, particularly iPhone devices after updating Xcode to v9.2 (I fixed that issue by making a slight change to my info.plist file).

Comment: Have you read [this](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http)? "If your organization has a firewall that restricts the traffic to or from the Internet, you need to configure it to allow connectivity with GCM in order for your GCM client apps to receive messages. The ports to open are: 5228, 5229, and 5230. GCM typically only uses 5228, but it sometimes uses 5229 and 5230. GCM doesn't provide specific IPs, so you should allow your firewall to accept outgoing connections to all IP addresses contained in the IP blocks listed in Google's ASN of 15169."

Comment: @noogui Thank you for taking the time to respond but please look at points 4 and 5. Both of those points, especially 5 prove that those ports are open. I did however work with the Network Admin to ensure those ports are open and we monitored the traffic to and from the device to be sure. Everything was flowing through the network properly.